# Авторизация PHP

Tags: php

Суть проблемы: если ввести левый логин и пароль просто заходит на сайт под тем логином и выдаетсья кука, если ввести правильный логин и неправильный пароль все работает ХОРОШО. Почему выдаетсья кука при введении неверного логина???

```
if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
    $connect = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","my_bd");
mysqli_query($connect ," SET NAMES 'utf8' ");
if (!$connect) {
    mysqli_error();
}


    $enter_login = $_POST['enter_login'];
    $enter_pswd = (int) $_POST['enter_pswd'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($connect,  " SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$enter_login' ");
    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql); 

    if ((int) $user_data['password'] == $enter_pswd) {
        setcookie('user',$enter_login,time()+36000); 
        header("Location:  /myblog/");
        exit;
    } else { echo "<script>alert(\"Неверный логин или пароль.\");</script>";  }


mysqli_close($connect);
}
```

Comment: эдак с такой охраной я зная имя произвольного пользователя могу вписать в запрос куку и авторизоваться что ли? вы куки с сессиями случаем не попутали?

Comment: Вы бы попробовали самостоятельно разобраться, что делает ваш код. Зачем вы приводите пароли к типу integer (`(int)`)?

Comment: работает у вас все криво как раз из-за упомянутого выше приведения к `int`. Когда вы приводите текстовую строку к целому числу то получаете значение 0. И это значение вы получаете оба раза, а потом сравниваете два нуля, в итоге получая, тождественное равенство.

Comment: а старая кука была удалена?

Comment: Когда я вводил логин правильный и пароль не правильный мне выдавало ошибко что пароль введен не верен, к этому у меня притензий не было)) Я не пойму почему получеться так что при вводе левого логина у меня выдаеться кука на него? Можете мне обьяснить это? Кука старая было удалена я чделал кнопку что отправляет браузеру ту же куку только со значением времени -3600.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К слову, недавно написал подобную проверку авторизации:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['isUserCorrect'])) {
    $_SESSION['isUserCorrect'] = FALSE;
}

if ($_SESSION['isUserCorrect']) {
    echo json_encode('redirect');
} else {
    $login = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['login']));
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
    $tmp_conn = new mysqli(Model::$host, Model::$username, Model::$password, Model::$dbname);
    if ($result = $tmp_conn->query("SELECT Login, Password FROM User WHERE Login = '$login' AND Password = '$password'")) {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $_SESSION['userLogin'] = $_POST['login'];
            $_SESSION['isUserCorrect'] = TRUE;
            echo json_encode('true');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['isUserCorrect'] = FALSE;
            echo json_encode('false');
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['isUserCorrect'] = FALSE;
        echo json_encode('false');
    }
    $tmp_conn->close();
}
```

$result получает объект *mysqli_result*, в котором можно проверить к-ство строк, вернувшихся БД. 
Если больше 0 - значит пользователь с таким логином и паролем есть, иначе - неверное, в js все это обрабатываю, но думаю в php-скрипте не сложно сделать свои манипуляции.

Comment: что будет если в качестве логина указать строку `qwe' or id = 1 #` или `'; delete from user; #`?

Comment: @teran спасибо, я почему-то полагал, что htmlspecialchars сделает всю работу ;)

Comment: а я вообще что-то просмотрел, что у вас перед подстановкой в запрос происходит какая-то обработка.

Comment: @teran, да, там было htmlspecialchars, но он вроде не особо справляется (хотя я 17 минут назад думал иначе)

Comment: оно заменяет одинарную кавычку при установке флага `ENT_QUOTES`

Answer (score 0):

По существу заданного вопроса. Кука выставляется по следующей причине.

При выполнении следующего кода,

```
$enter_pswd = (int) $_POST['enter_pswd'];
```

после приведения переданного пароля к типу `int` значение переменной `$enter_pswd`становится равным нулю, по скольку ваш пароль по-видимому содержит в том числе не только числовые символы.

Далее таким же образом вы выбираете пароль из БД, и опять приводите его к типу `int`. Получая опять же значение `0`. Следующим этапом вы сравниваете два нулевых значения, и конечно же получаете результат `true`.

Это объясняет, почему кука появлеятся при вводе некорректного пароля. Отмечу, что в случае, когда у вас пароль содержит только цифры кука не будет выдана. В общем итоге - приводить пароль к типу `int` не требуется, и не понятно зачем вы это делаете.

Далее несколько замечаний относительно вашего кода:

1. Подстановка логина напрямую в тело SQL запроса открывает прямой путь к инъекции кода. Представьте что в качестве логина кто-то напишет строку `xxxx' union select 1 as id, 'admin' as login, 123 as password; #`.

В итоге ваш запрос на проверку пользователя станет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = 'xxxx'
union
select 1 as id, 'admin' as login, 123 as password; #'
```

что в паре с указанием пароля `123` приведет к успешной авторизации. В других случаях в если качестве логина получится указать, например, `qwe'; delete from users; #` в рузультате чего содержимое таблицы пользователей будет удалено. Таким же образом получится и добавить новую запись в таблицу с небольшим подбором имен полей.

2. Не храните пароли в БД в открытом виде. Хранится должны хэши паролей, например, самый простой `md5()`.
3. Признак авторизации пользователя, очевидно, следует указывать не в куки, а в сессии. Т.к. первые открыто передаются между клиентом и сервером, и никто не мешает пользователю вписать туда что-угодно руками, исправив заголовки запроса в браузере.

Comment: Мне говорили пароль в sha1() закидывать, есть какая разница?

Comment: Хорошо я передам пароль с помощью md5 и проверю, бду использовать не куки а сессию. Но когда я вводил логин правильный и пароль не правильный мне выдавало ошибко что пароль введен не верен, к этому у меня притензий не было)) Я не пойму почему получеться так что при вводе левого логина у меня выдаеться кука на него? Можете мне обьяснить это? Пожалуйста.

Comment: @user225682 то есть у вас выдается алерт, что некорректный пароль, и вместе с тем кука выдается?

Comment: Нет если логин правильный а пароль не правильный кука не выдаеться просто показывает ошибку, а если логин не правильный то выдаетсья кука на этот логин. Я сейчас организовал всё через сессии и работает отлично, просто интересно почемутак происходило.

Comment: Просто юзай сесии так все делают

Comment: @ЮраПетров, sha1  - 160-битная хэш-функция, md5 - 128-битная хэш функция, разница в том, что вероятность коллизии в sha1 по идее меньше, следовательно, его использовать более целесообразно. Но, т.к. это не функция шифрования, а всего лишь способ не хранить пароли, то особой разницы нету, если Вы делаете небольшой веб-портал.